# ¿cómo depurar una "class"?

Tags: python, class, depuración

Es la primera vez que programo una class en python y en colab.

al compilarlo no me salen errores, pero al ejecutarlo si y no lo entiendo.

El código determina los parámetros geométricos de un rectángulo y calcula área, perímetro, lo escala y realiza un desplazamiento en el plano cartesiano.

mi código se encuentra en este [archivo](https://we.tl/t-q0tx8RmeEb):

El error que obtengo es:

```
Por favor introduzca el parametro de su preferencia para construir el rectangulo. Las opciones son     (introduzca solo el número) : 1. Vértices o 2. largo y ancho
1
Introduzca las coordenadas del vértice superior izquierdo
Introduzca x_sup_izq
0
Introduzca y_sup_izq
9
Introduzca las coordenadas del vértice inferior derecho
Introduzca x_inf_der
8
Introduzca y_inf_der
0
<__main__.rectangulo at 0x7f9dd5409c18>
```

¿qué me sugieren?

Comment: Coloca el código y no mandes un enlace externo para descargarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Python es un lenguaje de programación interpretado, no compilado.  Quizá un ejemplo te pueda ayudar para mejorar tú código.

```
class Celsius():
    def __init__(self,valor):
        self.valor=valor
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)
    
    def calculo(self):
        return (self.valor-32)/(9/5.0)

#main
celsius = Celsius(12)
resultado = celsius.calculo()
print("Valor: ",celsius.valor)
print("Resultado: ",resultado)
```

Salida:

```
{'valor': 12}
Valor:  12
Resultado:  -11.11111111111111
```

`__repr__` nos permite mostrar los campos o atributos de tu clase, de manera similar al toString() de Java.

En este link puedes ver una posible solución a tu problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832999/main-object-at-0x02c08790

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada un consejo: `input()` te permite introducir un texto tal que se muestre justo antes de la petición de valores, por ejemplo `input("Valor: ")`

En segundo lugar, la identación del `.txt` que adjuntas estaba extraña y requería de reposicionamiento.

Ahora sí, en cuanto al código puro, tenías un error en el cálculo de relaciones de la opción 1 (corregido) y te faltaban algunos `self.` en los return de alguna función (corregido). Nota interesante: el `self.` sobre una variable indica que el objeto almacenará dicha información. Si no quieres que perdure puedes retirar el `self.` y la variable sólo vivirá lo que dure el cálculo de la función.

Finalmente, entiendo que la salida que nos has compartido no es un error, más bien implica que has creado una instancia de rectangulo: `<este_programa.objeto at posición_de_memoria_del_pc>`

Si has creado una instancia `a = rectangulo()`, puedes acceder a sus valores directamente con `a.valor`, por ejemplo puedes probar `print(a.x_inf_izq)`.

**CÓDIGO MODIFICADO**

```
#definiendo el objeto
class rectangulo(): 
  def __init__(self, x_inf_izq = 0, x_sup_izq = 0, x_inf_der = 0, x_sup_der = 0, y_sup_izq = 0, y_sup_der = 0, y_inf_der = 0, y_inf_izq = 0, largo = 0, ancho = 0):

    #Preguntar al usario los parametros a introducir
    decision = int(input('Por favor introduzca el parametro de su preferencia para construir el rectangulo. Las opciones son (introduzca solo el número) : 1. Vértices o 2. largo y ancho\n'))
 
    if decision == 1:
      print('Introduzca las coordenadas del vértice superior izquierdo')
      self.x_sup_izq = int(input('Introduzca x_sup_izq\n'))
      self.y_sup_izq = int(input('Introduzca y_sup_izq\n'))
  
      print('Introduzca las coordenadas del vértice inferior derecho')
      self.x_inf_der = int(input('Introduzca x_inf_der\n'))
      self.y_inf_der = int(input('Introduzca y_inf_der\n'))
  
      #relaciones
      self.x_inf_izq = self.x_sup_izq
      self.x_sup_der = self.x_inf_der
      self.y_sup_der = self.y_sup_izq
      self.y_inf_izq = self.y_inf_der
      
      self.ancho = abs(self.y_sup_izq - self.y_inf_izq)
      self.largo = abs(self.x_inf_der - self.x_inf_izq)


    elif decision ==2:
      print('Introduzca el largo y ancho del rectangulo')
      self.largo = int(input('Introduzca el largo del rectangulo\n'))
      self.ancho = int(input('Introduzca el ancho del rectangulo\n'))
      #relaciones
      self.x_inf_izq = self.x_sup_izq = 0
      self.x_inf_der = self.x_sup_der = self.largo
      self.y_sup_izq = self.y_sup_der = self.ancho
      self.y_inf_der = self.y_inf_izq = 0

    #calcular área del rectangulo
    def area(self): #definir la funcion
      self.area = self.largo * self.ancho
      return area

    # calcular el perimetro del rectangulo
    def perimetro(self):
      self.perimetro = 2*self.largo + 2*self.ancho
      return perimetro

    #escalar al cuadrado
    def escalar(self):
      self.escalar = int(input("Introduzca el valor por el cual escalar\n"))
      self.largoe = self.escalar*self.largo
      self.anchoe = self.escalar*self.ancho
      return self.largoe, self.anchoe

    # hacer desplazamiento
    def desplazar(self):
      self.desplazarx = int(input("Introduzca el valora desplazar en x\n"))
      self.desplazary = int(input("Introduzca el valora desplazar en y\n"))

      self.x_inf_izq_n = self.desplazarx + self.x_inf_izq
      self.x_sup_izq_n = self.desplazarx + self.x_sup_izq
      self.x_sup_der_n = self.desplazarx + self.x_sup_der
      self.x_inf_der_n = self.desplazarx + self.x_inf_der

      self.y_inf_izq_n = self.desplazary + self.y_inf_izq
      self.y_sup_izq_n = self.desplazary + self.y_sup_izq
      self.y_sup_der_n = self.desplazary + self.y_sup_der
      self.y_inf_der_n = self.desplazary + self.y_inf_der

      return self.x_inf_izq_n, self.y_inf_izq_n, self.x_sup_izq_n, self.y_sup_izq_n, self.x_sup_der_n, self.y_sup_der_n, self.x_inf_der_n, self.y_inf_der_n
```

Espero que sea útil ;)